# how do to hide that " user is typing " message in pidgin?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, pidgin

how do to hide  that " user is typing " message  in pidgin?

Comment: Do you want to hide the fact you are typing from others, or you don't want to see that others are typing?

Comment: i want to hide the face i am typing to others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want others to know you are typing, you should uncheck the "Notify buddies that you are typing to them" in the "Conversation" tab in the "Preferences" window.